# Any picture Gallery Control for .NET 1.1 in WinForms?

Tags: .net, winforms, image-gallery, .net-1.1

I need a UserControl to display pictures as a Gallery in Winforms. I have my pictures as a Image Collection but no problem to change to fit Control capabilities.

It could be nice if it is for .NET 1.1  but since I'm planning to migrate all our code to 2.0 if the control is in that framework it could be useful in the future

If it is free much better :)

Does any of you know a control like this?

Comment: Surely this is easy enough to write on your own, as a user control?

Comment: Yeap... a really simple one at least. But a boxed control could have some nice features (metadata display, enlarge a picture while showing the others as thumbnails, show gallery as a slideshow... and a big etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there's nothing built in to display a Gallery but if you're willing to use 2.0 you can throw one together with the TableLayoutPanel pretty easily.